# How to dump a single table from database using drush?

Tags: drush

I'm aware of mysqldump utility, but is there any way of dumping a single table from database using drush (e.g. for sql-dump, sql-sync)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use **--tables-list** option on drush command to dump specific tables.

```
drush sql-dump --tables-list=node,system > exportdb.sql
```

Above command will only make sql-dump for **node** and **system** tables.

[Source](http://drushcommands.com/drush-6x/sql/sql-dump)

Comment: First of all "--table-list" is unknown option. Actually "-table**s**-list" is used.
Second thing that correct option "--tables-list" is not working on Windows machine and full DB dump will be created instead.

Comment: Tested `drush sql-dump --tables-list=rules_config --ordered-dump` on Drush 8.1-dev, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Full DB dump will be created if the table in tables-list doesn't exitsts (may due misspeling or not adding prefix) - https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3708 .